# How to scale Qt widgets with automatic layout on hight DPI screen?

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to follow the long-term path as stated in [document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#migrate-existing-applications) so automatic scaling like `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` is not acceptable.

Without a layout, I can use a value from `devicePixelRatioF` to scale the widgets. When using layout the size and position of the widgets will be handled by the layout. So how do scale widgets according to screen DPI in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controlling scale you need to use layouts.see [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) document.

and [Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum)

> Enables high-DPI scaling in Qt on supported platforms (see also High
> DPI Displays). Supported platforms are X11, Windows and Android.
> Enabling makes Qt scale the main (device independent) coordinate
> system according to display scale factors provided by the operating
> system. This corresponds to setting the QT_AUTO_SCREEN​_SCALE_FACTOR
> environment variable to 1. This attribute must be set before

so add this line in your `main.cpp`

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

**Updated:**

When a widget enters the layout you can't change its width or height from the geometry section BUT you can change its size policy or scale widgets with Max/Min section.
This doesn't relate to DPI.

[image]

from Doc that you mentioned it says that:

> In the long term, the application should be adapted to run unmodified:
>
> - Always use the qreal versions of the QPainter drawing API.
> - Size windows and dialogs in relation to the corresponding screen size.
> - Replace hard-coded sizes in layouts and drawing code with values calculated from font metrics or screen size.

**means that you should follow that 3 suggestions**

means that you can calculate the size by yourself. (hard-coded)
In my experience, I never have an issue with scale when I use layout on different devices or monitors.

**I need to know what you see on your screen and what expect to be.**

Comment: AFAIK `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` has the same effect as `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR`, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon , so I didn't understand your problem , could you add some code and pictures to your question?

Comment: Please take a look on Qt documentation that I provided above. In the last paragraph they said "In the long term, the application should be adapted to run unmodified:". I want to follow this path which I already known for widgets that does not controlled by a layout. But when a layout kick in I can't control the size of the widgets anymore.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon I update my answer, DPI is important when you are testing your app on multiple devices or OS, but If you want just scale widget when you are using layouts you should set Min/Max and that will correct its DPI automatically in different devices.

Comment: You are right. I have tested and found out the layout system already handled DPI for me.